# ¿Como quitar recuadro al botón?

Tags: css, css3

¿Alguien me sabría decir que es este recuadro azul que le sale al botón? ¿Y como se elimina?

Yo pensé que con `text-decoration: none;` bastaría pero se sigue quedando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega código de lo que describes en tus preguntas, esto para que sean de utilidad a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remueve la propiedad [`outline`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) del button:

```css
button{
border-radius:10px;
outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Button con el outline por defecto:

```css
button{
border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<button>con outline por defecto</button
```